# How to make a query to obtain only results that have N number within a range of values?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, multiple-tables

I'm trying to extract nutrient data in MS Access 2007 from the USDA food database, freely available at http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=24912

I need records that have ALL nutrients from NUT_DATA.Nutr_No  . Those records have values between '501' and '511' . But I wish to exclude incomplete records that have missing values.

Currently, Baby food banana has all from nutrient 501 to 511, but Baby food Beverage has only 9 of the nutrients listed, and many others are like that.

As a last resort, I guess it would be acceptable to have all records, showing null for missing values, as long as each FOOD_DES.Long_Desc has exactly 11 records, one for each NUT_DATA.Nutr_No OR NUTR_DEF.NutrDesc (which correspond to each other).

```
SELECT 
FOOD_DES.NDB_No,  FOOD_DES.FdGrp_Cd, FOOD_DES.Long_Desc, NUT_DATA.Nutr_No, NUTR_DEF.NutrDesc, NUT_DATA.Nutr_Val, WEIGHT.Amount, WEIGHT.Msre_Desc, WEIGHT.Gm_Wgt, [WEIGHT]![Amount] & " " & [WEIGHT]![Msre_Desc] AS msre

FROM 
NUTR_DEF inner JOIN ((FOOD_DES INNER JOIN NUT_DATA ON FOOD_DES.NDB_No=NUT_DATA.NDB_No) INNER JOIN WEIGHT ON FOOD_DES.NDB_No=WEIGHT.NDB_No) ON NUTR_DEF.Nutr_No=NUT_DATA.Nutr_No
WHERE 
   (NUT_DATA.Nutr_No between '501' and '511'  ) and ((WEIGHT.Seq)="1") and  NUT_DATA.Nutr_Val > '0' and
```

// this part is me out of ideas trying stuff, but didn't help

```
 EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM 
        NUTR_DEF inner JOIN ((FOOD_DES INNER JOIN NUT_DATA ON FOOD_DES.NDB_No=NUT_DATA.NDB_No) INNER JOIN WEIGHT ON FOOD_DES.NDB_No=WEIGHT.NDB_No) ON NUTR_DEF.Nutr_No=NUT_DATA.Nutr_No

            WHERE  count FOOD_DES.Long_Desc = "11"        )
```

//end wild of experimentation

```
   ORDER BY FOOD_DES.Long_Desc, NUTR_DEF.SR_Order;
```

This is a sample of the data. I just copied the most important columns. The red is not what I'm looking for because it doesn't have all 11 nutrients. I can paste on the google doc the whole table if someone thinks that would help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FghDD59wy2PYlpsqUlYVc3Ulwvy4MMLagpBUYtvLBfI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You should edit your question and show some sample data and the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your starting point, identify which food items have values > 0 for all 11 of those nutrients.  Check whether this simpler `GROUP BY` query shows you the correct items:

```sql
SELECT ndat.NDB_No
FROM
    NUT_DATA AS ndat
    INNER JOIN WEIGHT AS wt
    ON ndat.NDB_No = wt.NDB_No
WHERE
        ndat.Nutr_Val>0
    AND ndat.Nutr_No IN('501','502','503','504','505','506','507','508','509','510','511')
    AND wt.Seq='1'
GROUP BY ndat.NDB_No
HAVING Count(ndat.Nutr_No)=11;
```

Note you could use `Val(ndat.Nutr_No) Between 501 And 511` as the *Nutr_No* restriction, which would give you a more concise statement.  However, evaluating `Val()` for every row of the table means that approach would forego the performance benefit of indexed retrieval ... so that version of the query should be noticeably slower.

Save that query and create a new query which joins it to the base tables for the additional data you need from other columns.  Or use it as a subquery instead of a named query if you prefer.

Comment: joining as a sub-query was not well received by ms-access, 
but selecting the result of this query into a new table, then joining my original query with this "temporary table", worked. Thanks!